# Python Mechanize login form, sending input to a field with a randomly generated name

Tags: python, html, forms, authentication, mechanize

I'm trying to automate the login to a site, http://www.tthfanfic.org/login.php.

The problem I am having is that the password field has a name that is randomly generated, I have tried using it's label, type and id all of which remain static but to no avail.

Here is the HTML of the form:

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="urealname">User Name</label></th>
    <td><input type='text' id='urealname' name='urealname' value=''/> NOTE: Your user name may not be the same as your pen name.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="password">Password</label></th><td><input type='password' id='password' name='e008565a17664e26ac8c0e13af71a6d2'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Remember Me</th><td><input type='checkbox' id='remember' name='remember'/>
<label for="remember">Log me in automatically for two weeks on this computer using a cookie. </label> Do not select this option if this is a public computer, or you have an evil sibling.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='2' style="text-align:center">
        <input type='submit' value='Login' name='loginsubmit'/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried to format that for readability but it still looks bad, consider checking the code on the supplied page.

Here is the code I get when printing the form through mechanize:

```
<POST http://www.tthfanfic.org/login.php application/x-www-form-urlencoded

  <HiddenControl(ctkn=a40e5ff08d51a874d0d7b59173bf3d483142d2dde56889d35dd6914de92f2f2a) (readonly)>

  <TextControl(urealname=)>

  <PasswordControl(986f996e16074151964c247608da4aa6=)>

  <CheckboxControl(remember=[on])>

  <SubmitControl(loginsubmit=Login) (readonly)>>
```

The number sequence in the PasswordControl is the part that changes each time I reload the page, in the HTML from the site it seems to have several other tags ascribed to it but none of them work when I try to select them, that or I'm doing it incorrectly.

Here is the code I am using to try and select the control by label:

```
fieldTwo = br.form.find_control(label='password')

    br[fieldOne] = identifier

    br[fieldTwo] = password
```

I can post the rest of my login code if neccesary but this is the only part that is not working, I have had success with other sites where the password name remains the same.

So, is it possible for me to select the passwordControl using it's label, type or ID, or do I need to scrape its name?

EDIT: Oops, forgot to add the error message:

```
raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching "+description)

mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching label 'password'
```

SOLVED:

Solution given by a guy on reddit, thanks Bliti.

Working code:

```
br.select_form(nr=2)
list = []
    for f in br.form.controls:           
        list.append(f.name)
    fieldTwo = list[2]
```

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it so others can know the solution and this won't remain as an open question!

Comment: Ah, will do, wouldn't let me do it at the time due to my rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution given by a guy on reddit, thanks Bliti.

Working code:

```
#Select the form you want to use.
br.select_form(nr=2)
list = []
    for f in br.form.controls: 
        #Add the names of each item in br.formcontrols          
        list.append(f.name)
    #Select the correct one from the list.
    fieldTwo = list[2]
```